# Dart SDK version issue with null safety "The `--null-safety` flag is no longer supported"

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I had built an app in Flutter 2.10.3 SDK (Dart SDK 2.16.1) version a year ago. I just installed latest Flutter 3.10.4 SDK (Dart SDK 3.0.3) on Windows 10. I use Android Studio as IDE. I have tried to run the null safety, but when I type and enter "`dart pub upgrade --null-safety`", it occurs as the following error message:

```
The `--null-safety` flag is no longer supported.
Consider using the Dart 2.19 sdk to migrate to null safety.
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Dart SDK 2.16.1 is already NNBD, so you have no migration to do there.  There have been breaking changes to both Dart and Flutter in the meanwhile, but overall, changes should be minor.

You might have an IDE flag set to invoke the --null-safety flag. You should remove that now.  That was meant from when you were migrating from pre-2.12 to 2.12 of Dart.

Comment: Should I change the updated version in pubspec.yaml manually?

Comment: When you are certain that the code complies with a new sdk level, yes.